# POLL: What do you call your business layer base namespace?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a simple solution with the following projects as follows (base namespaces match the project name)...

MyCompany.MyProduct.BusinessLayer
MyCompany.MyProduct.Web.Service
MyCompany.MyProduct.Web.Site

I'm just trying to find a better name for BusinessLayer, I just don't really like it for some reason. So my question is what do you call your BusinessLayer projects/namespaces.

article on namespace guidelines
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx

Comment: Polls tend to work better if they're marked Community Wiki (edit your post and click the checkbox). Otherwise, they tend to encourage duplicate responses (rather than voting up/down on existing answers).

Comment: Polls don't work at all in the SO format imo. Either duplicates happen anyway or since anyone can add a valid poll response, the results are so diluted as to be useless.

Comment: Polls also suffer from the "fastest gun" problem, not that it matters too terribly much.

Comment: Yeah, the incredible accuracy of normal Internet Polls just doesn't carry through to SO polls. ;-P

I suspect these questions get asked more in the hopes that someone will provide a well-reasoned answer that the author agrees with, than out of any real desire for consensus. Meh...

Comment: Shog9 - you're correct, I'm just hoping for something I agree with. I'm going with "Business"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would drop the "Layer" suffix:  MyCompany.MyProduct.Business

Answer (score 7):

We just use BL because it stands for both Business Layer and BudLight.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've just called it "Business".

Answer (score 1):

Why map the layers directly in a one-to-one relationship with namespaces in the first place? Layering is a technique to break apart complicated software systems. It’s a way of seeing the principal subsystems arranged like a cake, where each layer rests upon a lower layer. Higher layers use services from lower layers, but the lower layers are unaware of the higher. An application can easily have multiple packages of each the subject areas (presentation, business, data source).

For example, in a web application, the HTML and CSS is part of the presentation layer, but neither of these documents would reside in the MyCompany.MyProduct.PresentationLayer namespace.

So, to answer your question “What do you call your business layer base namespace?” absolutely nothing. Such a namespace shouldn’t exist. Namespaces should be named by features. *Business layer* is *not* a feature. Neither is *presentation layer, data layer, or service layer*.

Just my two bits.

Answer (score 0):

Ours are:

```
CompanyName.CentralClassLibrary
CompanyName.Utilities.*
CompanyName.TradingTools.*
```

The first is mostly classes from the original version of our application, which describe the central trading objects. The second is classes that provide non-trading specific functionality (configuration, multi-machine, etc.) The third is for specific domains of trading (one for each service we talk to, one for calculating value, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I do Client.Project.BusinessObjects

Answer (score 0):

In Java, I use the `com.companyname.applicationname.*` "standard," even though it's a little old-school.

In C#, I use the `CompanyName.ApplicationName.*` approach.

In both cases `*` will usually be `business` for the business layer, `data` for the data layer, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Our Business Logic and Data Access Layers

CompanyName.ApplicationName.BLL
CompanyName.ApplicationName.DAL

An alternative might be BusObj or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Company.Product.FunctionalDomain.Biz

Answer (score 0):

I've seen BusinessLogic, but it as noted by the rest of the answers here a lot of time you will see...

- MyCompany.MyProduct.DataAccessLayer (or DAL)
- MyCompany.MyProduct.BusinessEntities (or BusinessObjects)
- MyCompany.MyProduct.BusinessLogic
- MyCompany.MyProduct.Web.Service
- MyCompany.MyProduct.Web.Site

Another good reference for this type of stuff is the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756) book.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the apps we work on use DAL for Data Access Layer and BR for Business Rules...